# use requirejs load jquery plugs datatables ,have an error

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

i use `requirejs` load `datatable` plug,i got an error `$().dataTable()`is not function,

this is my js code:

```
define(function() {
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/Scripts",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "/Libs/jquery.min"
        "jquery.datatable": "/Libs/dataTable/js/jquery.dataTables.min"
    },
    map: {
        "*": {
            "css": "/Libs/cssjs/css.js"
        }
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery": {
            exports: "$"
        },
        "jquery.datatable":"jquery"
    },
    waitSeconds: 15,
});})
```

this is page js

```
define(["jquery.datatable"], function() {
$(function() {
    $("#example").dataTable();
});
```

});

when i run it ,i got an error on my console :

`TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function`

`jquery version is v1.11.0`

`DataTables version is v1.10.7`

`RequireJS version is v2.1.11`

can u help me? thanks

Comment: the datatables plug  is loaded but can not use id

Comment: yeah i got it .,just need change the datatables js name to `datatables` ,it was work perfect all code like this :

Answer (score 0):

i solved this question 
update the requirejs config like this :

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: "/Scripts",
paths: {
    "jquery": "/Libs/jquery.min",
    "datatables": "/Libs/dataTable/js/jquery.dataTables.min"
},
map: {
    "*": {
        "css": "/Libs/cssjs/css.js"
    }
},
shim: {
    "jquery": {
        exports: "$"
    },
    "datatables":"jquery"
},
waitSeconds: 15,
```

});})

Note:
the datatables's path,the paths name must be `datatables`.